# What is the middleground between permatube and normal tubes?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, innertube, sealant

I've burst my third tyre in two months on my MTB, each time it's caused by something sharp penetrating my tyre at high speed ripping a big enough hole in the tube causing the slime to leak out rapidly followed by a struggle to maintain control of the bike.

So I've considered permatubes, but read that they add a lot of weight to the MTB and are rock hard, so the ride will be extra hard.

Is there some sort of middle ground? Permatubes are rock hard, but will never put me in a position where I have to walk the last 15km of a 40km trail, normal tubes I can inflate / deflate depending on whether I cycle on road or offroad, but it seems slime is not enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried belted tires?  In my experience they reduce punctures by at least a factor of ten.

Comment: Never heard of belted tires before, would the "Schwalbe Racing Ralph Evo Snakeskin" be considered a belted tyre?

Comment: I prefer the Forte Kevlar-belted tires, though the Schwalbe tires ("Gatorskin" brand, I believe) are quite popular.  I feel the Forte tires are lighter and more flexible since they use the Kevlar fabric belt instead of a thick plastic one.

Comment: I don't see it available anywhere in ZA, will do a bit more digging, thanks for the advice! The options I can easily access seems to be `Continental X-King Protection`, `Schwalbe Racing Ralph Evo Snakeskin`, `Kenda Tyre Honey Badger` (not sure if this is a belted tyre), `Vittoria Peyote` (they mention kevlar beads, so not sure if it's belted either)

Comment: Kevlar bead is not the same as a Kevlar belt.  Kevlar bead is for a "folding" tire, which you really only want if you carry a spare tire in your fanny pack.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - A Kevlar bead is also lighter than a steel bead.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak - A Kevlar bead also makes the tire very difficult to mount.  The half ounce or so weight savings is not worth it.

Comment: "What is the middleground between permatube and normal tubes?"  One of each.  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutube are not good to ride on

Middle ground is a heavier puncture resistant tire if you are running racing tires

Spare tubeS, tire patch, tube patches, and a pump.

Tubeless has a lower risk of failure but field repair is harder (you can put a tube in a tubeless).

Comment: I'm not racing at all, just want to get away from the nuisance of having to replace tyres mid-ride or being stuck on the track if I forgot to pack the spare tubes. What is the benefit of heavier tyres, are they less puncture prone? Any specific ones you would recommend? I see some people put 'n piece of plastic inside their tyre to protect the tube, are those any good?

Comment: Then don't forget to pack spare tubes.  I did not say are you racing. I said are you running racing tires.   Racing tires will be light weight and say race in description.   Come one,  yes heavier tires are stronger.    A site like schwalbetires has a puncture rating.  I don't like inserts as they abrade the tube.

Comment: Had no idea there were even such a thing as racing tyres, hence the confusion. Thought a tyre was a tyre and that the rest was all marketing nonsense. My sidewalls have the words "Merida Race" written in huge white letters, so I'm assuming I have racing tyres. Will look into belted tyres as @Daniel mentioned, they sound like they can handle South African conditions a bit better, my current tyres are almost finished in any case after just 2000km.

Comment: If it says "Merida Race" then no, it's not a racing tire, just some heavy OEM stock specimen.